# Convert pyspark groupedData to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to groupby via Spark a large dataset that I loaded as a two columns Pandas dataframe and then re-convert into Pandas: basically doing Pandas -> 'pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData' -> Pandas.
Elements in both columns are integers, and the grouped data need to be stored in list format as follows:

```
df.a        df.b
1            3
2            5
3            8
1            2
3            1
2            6
...
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_grouped_df = spark_df.groupBy('a')
type: <class 'pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData'>
```

At this point, I need to have is something like this as Pandas df (afterwards I need to do other operations more pandas friendly):

```
a        b
1    | [3,2]
2    | [5,6] 
3    | [8,1]
...
```

If using pandas, I would do this, but is too time consuming:

```
grouped_data = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('a',as_index = True, sort = True)['b'].apply(list))
```

With Spark I'm sure would be way faster.

Any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: did you check `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas` http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas

Comment: @ MedAli I checked it and I could use it if the object was a     pyspark.sql.DataFrame; the one resulting from groupby() is of type     pyspark.sql.group.GroupedData

Comment: you could convert the dataframe before group to an pandas one and then perform the group by in pandas.

Comment: As a general principle: when your data fit into main memory, Spark will always be **slower** than pandas (or any other framework for 'non-big data')

Comment: @csbr you need to accept the answers that solved your issue !

Answer (score 4):

You need to aggregate over grouped data. To get your output  format, you can use collect_list function,

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
>>> pdf = spark_df.groupby('a').agg(collect_list('b').alias('b')).toPandas()
>>> pdf.head()
       a    b
    0  1  [3, 2]
    1  3  [8, 1]
    2  2  [5, 6]
```